# How to properly use save method from Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering how should I deal with the save method. Let's consider a situation when I want to register a new user. Firstly I need to check if there is one with that Id or login. If I can not find anyone I am able to create a new one and use save method from Spring Data.

What in the case when I found someone with such login? Should I throw an exception? I don't like them, for me, it's sometimes like running away from a problem. Returning a null instead of an object is not a good choice either, isn't it? That is my problem which I want to solve in the most gentle way. What to return and how to deal with such a situation. Maybe the exception is necessary? Then just handle it in my controller and deal with it. I hope you will advise me. I am rather asking for tips and a few words from experienced guys rather than getting an ordinary solution from the majority of pages on the internet. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception literally means "I couldn't complete this operation normally because of a circumstance outside the ordinary workflow", and `AccountAlreadyExists` is a perfect example of when *to* throw an exception. You're not "running away", you're informing a higher layer of the application that it will have to handle the problem. As a thought experiment: What if you have *more than one reason* that something could fail? How do you distinguish between `null` (duplicate account) and `null` (banned domain name)?

Note in this case that you definitely should have something like a `UserAccountService` whose responsibility is enforcing rules like "no duplicate accounts", and this will be the object that actually calls `userRepository.save(newUser)`.

If you're using Spring MVC views, then you'll want to catch the exception in your controller and send the user to an error page. If you're using a JSON API, then you'll probably want to let the exception escape to return an error to the client; consider annotating your exception class with `@ResponseStatus(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)` or similar.